# SQL Oracle Specify start point using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

I got this code:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ID ORDER BY ID DESC, year DESC, month DESC, day DESC) rank
```

I would like to fix the exactly year, month and day to start to rank. 
Where should i put this condition in that situacion?

Thank you in advance!

**-----------------------------------------------------EDIT:----------------------------------------------------**

I'm going to detail better my situtation in order to show you what I exactly want.

Let's use this sample table and assume there are values for every date.

```
| Year | Month | Day | ID        | Rank       |
|------|-------|-----|-----------|------------|
| 2017 | 9     | 14  | 9555      | 1          |
| 2017 | 9     | 13  | 9555      | 2          |
| 2017 | 9     | 12  | 9555      | 3          |
| 2017 | 9     | 11  | 9555      | 4          |
| 2017 | 9     | 14  | 3000      | 1          |
| 2017 | 9     | 13  | 3000      | 2          |
| 2017 | 9     | 12  | 3000      | 3          |
| 2017 | 9     | 11  | 3000      | 4          |
```

This table is what you can get using the following code:

```
Select *
From (Select Year,
             Month,
             Day,
             ID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ID ORDER BY ID DESC, Year DESC, Month DESC, Day DESC) rank
      From table1
      Where (Condition)
      )
Where Rank < 5;
```

Our sample table is conditioned by the fact that the most recent row is from 14/09/2017.
My question is how could I get the last 4 rows from 13/09/2017?

Comment: so you want that date to start at 1 and all others before it to be null?

Comment: No idea what you're trying to ask - perhaps if you added *sample data* and *expected results*, it would be clearer. I would note, however, that having the same columns in both the `partition by` and `order by` clauses usually makes no sense whatsoever (hint: if you're partitioning by a particular column then all rows within each partition have, by definition, the same value in that column)

Comment: @xQbert, Damien_The_Unbeliever. I edited my question so you can understand what I was asking.

Comment: Wouldn't you just update the where condition (of the inner query) to stipulate `where to_date(Year||lpad(Month,2,0)||lpad(Day,2,0),'YYYYMMDD') <= to_date('13/09/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')`?  convert to date so I don't have to handle the beginning of month edge cases or leap years or etc.  I simply let the date datatype handle that for me.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks, it works, like the solution MT0 put above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR( year, 'FM0000' )
         || '-' || TO_CHAR( month, 'FM00' )
         || '-' || TO_CHAR( day, 'FM00' ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD'
       ) > DATE '2017-01-01' -- Your start date
  THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ID
                          ORDER BY ID DESC, year DESC, month DESC, day DESC)
END AS rank
```

But **why** are you storing a date in `year`, `month` and `day` columns rather than just one `DATE` data-type?

**Update**:

> how could I get the last 4 rows from 13/09/2017

This will get apply your rank only to rows on or before 2017-09-13:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ID 
                            ORDER BY ID DESC, Year DESC, Month DESC, Day DESC) rank
  FROM   table1 t
  WHERE  TO_DATE(
           TO_CHAR( year, 'FM0000' )
           || '-' || TO_CHAR( month, 'FM00' )
           || '-' || TO_CHAR( day, 'FM00' ),
           'YYYY-MM-DD'
         ) <= DATE '2017-09-13'
)
WHERE rank < 5
```

Comment: Thanks MT0, but I think this solution is not what I am finding. You can check my original question I have editied. I would like that this Date condition affect the whole query, not only the row_number() field.

Comment: @Roy90 Updated.

Comment: Thanks MT0, now it is working as it is expected. I will try to use this Select on an Update. Lets see if everything goes fine.